# Python is it possible to store tuple coordinates in a nested dict and access a single coordinate from a single dict within the nested dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, tuples, cartesian-coordinates

I have some code that uses a dict to store coordinate values. I would prefer to have something that had a key 'R1N1' and the value would be a tuple of the x and y coordinates but I don't know if that is possible in python or how you would index a key-tuple for either its x or y component:

**Code**

```
import json

rnID = dict ([
('R1N1x', 1),
('R1N1y', 111),
('R1N500x', 222),
('R1N500y', 222),
('R2N1x', 1),
('R2N1y', 111),
('R2N500x', 222),
('R2N500y', 222)
])

with open('rnID.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(rnID, outfile)
```

this works at storing coordinates but is a bit longwinded.

**Desired output**

```
something like 
new_dict = {[
('R1N1',(1,111))
...
```

Comment: why not store the coordinates like `{'R1N1': {'x': 1, 'y': 111}, ... }`?

Comment: Thanks @MjZac How would you read and write to the dict tuples that way?

Comment: How would you just *store a single coordinate*? Then, the thing that you use to do that, becomes a value in the dict you want. I really think you're overthinking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
rns = {}
for k, v in rnID.items():   
    part = k[-1]
    k = k[:-1]
    if k not in rns:
        rns[k] = [0, 0]
    rns[k][0 if part == 'x' else 1] = v

print(rns)
```

Output

```
{'R1N1': [1, 111], 'R1N500': [222, 222], 'R2N1': [1, 111], 'R2N500': [222, 222]}
```